# Can't save data in database in Grails manually but with dbconsole it works well

Tags: database, grails, gsp

From **`Register.gsp`** page when I submit the form it's render well and goes to list page. But the problem is it does not save any data. If I add data by `dbconsole`, then **`list.gsp`** shows the data. May be silly question, but I am very beginner in Grails. Thanks in advance.

**Domain Class :**

```
 package userreg

 class Customer {

 String name
 Date birthday
 String gender
 String email


static constraints = {
    name blank: false
    email blank: false,unique:true
  }
}
```

**Controller :**

```
package userreg

class CustomerController {
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

def index ={
     render(view:'register')

}

def register()
{

}

def save ={
  def customer=new Customer(params)
  customer.save flush:true
  redirect action:"list"
  }


def list() 
{
 def customers=Customer.list()
 [customers:customers]
}
}
```

**View - Register :**

```
register.gsp
<!doctype html>
  <head>
 <title>Registration </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="body">
<g:form controller="customer" action="save" >
 <table>
 <tr><td>Name</td><td><g:textField name="name"/> </td></tr>
 <tr><td>Birthday</td><td><g:datePicker name="date" value="${new Date()}"
          noSelection="['':'-Choose-']"/></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Gender</td><td><g:radio name="gender" value="female"/>Female
        <g:radio name="gender" value="male"/>Male</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Email</td><td><g:textField name="email" value="user@email.com"/>
  </td></tr>               
  <tr><td></td><td><g:submitButton name="save" value="save" /> </td></tr>
  </table>

  </g:form>
  <div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**List - list.gsp :**

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <title>List of Customers </title>
</head>

<body>
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th> Birthday</th>
        </tr>
        <g:each in="${customers}" var="customer">
            <tr>
                <td>${customer.name}</td>
                <td>${customer.gender}</td>
                <td>${customer.birthday}</td>
            </tr>
        </g:each>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to do, what did you try, and what results did you get? Update the body of the question. Reminder: no one here wants to debug your code for you. You need to show you are willing to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not saving probably because it has validation error.

Change

```
def save ={
  def customer=new Customer(params)
  customer.save flush:true
  redirect action:"list"
}
```

to this

```
def save ={
  def customer=new Customer(params)
  customer.save flush:true, failOnError:true
  redirect action:"list"
}
```

It will throw an error explaining the reason why it was not able to save the model.

Comment: A better idea is to check the return value of calling `.save(...)` and or inspect the `errors` property.